# Reduce Ajax calls and Refresh dataset at backend every second

Tags: c#, jquery

I want to reduce ajax call for getting best performance .
is there any other way to get lattest data from DB every second or after few seconds without sending ajax call.
I want to get data from that object.By this performance will be better.
Is there any way he hit DB and get lattest record and these operation should be hidden..

did u understand what i want ..?

Comment: have a look at http://signalr.net/

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometAsync.aspx

It implements both client and server in c# (ASP.NET for server)